# Get year/month/day h/m/s/ns from Boost local_date_time object?

Tags: c++, boost

I have converted a timestamp (UTC) since Epoch to a `boost::posix_time::ptime` and applied a timezone, resulting in a `boost::local_time::local_date_time` object. However, I cannot retrieve the year, month, day, hh/mm/ss/ns or nanoseconds since midnight for the adjusted date time.

It appears the `local_date_time` object doesn't provide getters for these.

I can't get these from the `boost::posix_time::ptime` because it hasn't been shifted for timezone.

What's the best approach?

```
using namespace boost::gregorian;
using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::posix_time;

// Create timezone
tz_database tz_db;      
tz_db.load_from_file("libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv");
time_zone_ptr chicago_tz = tz_db.time_zone_from_region("America/Chicago");
   
// Create Epoch offset (seconds) 
std::time_t btime_ = nanosSinceEpochUTC / 1E9;
ptime dateTime = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_);

// Create local Chicago time at Epoch offset
const local_date_time chicago(dateTime, chicago_tz);

// I need to retrieve the year/month/day/hh/mm/ss etc from the adjusted time, not the ptime.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time properties are in the `time_of_day()` sub object. The *representation* type of that subobject is `time_duration` and it has all the accessors you want:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be9953e68570011a)**

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/tz_db_base.hpp>

int main() {
    // Create timezone
    boost::local_time::tz_database tz_db;      
    {
        std::istringstream iss(R"("America/Chicago","CST","Central Standard Time","CDT","Central Daylight Time","-06:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00")");
        tz_db.load_from_stream(iss);
    }
    auto chicago_tz = tz_db.time_zone_from_region("America/Chicago");

    // Create Epoch offset (seconds) 
    std::time_t btime_ = 1596241091; // nanosSinceEpochUTC / 1E9;
    auto dateTime = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_);
    std::cout << "ptime: " << dateTime << "\n";

    // Create local Chicago time at Epoch offset
    const boost::local_time::local_date_time chicago(dateTime, chicago_tz);
    std::cout << "local_date_time: " << chicago << "\n";

    // I need to retrieve the year/month/day/hh/mm/ss etc from the adjusted
    // time, not the ptime.
    std::cout << "year/m/d:    " << chicago.local_time().date() << "\n";
    auto tod = chicago.local_time().time_of_day();
    std::cout << "time_of_day: " << tod << "\n";
    std::cout << "hh, mm, ss:  " << 
        tod.hours() << ", " <<
        tod.minutes() << ", " <<
        tod.seconds() << "\n";
}
```

> As you can see, it's important to access through the `local_time()` accessor. Note how all the items (day, month, hours) wrapped back correctly according to the time zone.

Prints:

```
ptime: 2020-Aug-01 00:18:11
local_date_time: 2020-Jul-31 19:18:11 CDT
year/m/d:    2020-Jul-31
time_of_day: 19:18:11
hh, mm, ss:  19, 18, 11
```

Comment: Added demo **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be9953e68570011a)**

Answer (score -1):

What I do is as follows: I am naming one class after the name of a time zone. In my case gmt and fetch everything via instances of my very own time as well as date class.

```
 class gmt {
     string get(string& s) {
             this->dt= this->d.getDay();
             this->tm= this->d.getTime();
             s= "expires="+this->d.getName(this->d.getDayName())
                     +", " +this->dt.substr( 0, 2) +"-" +this->d.getMonthName() +"-" +this->dt.substr( 8, 2)
                     +" " +this->tm +" GMT";
             return s;
     }
    
    friend class cookie;
    string dt, tm;
    MyDate d;
};
```

Okay, it isn't "boost" but you can solve it via its own std and isn't that contrary.